# Unexpectedly simple patterns for the determinants of some matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, toeplitz-matrices

**Edit: "Spoiler"**

Since it's a pretty wordy question, here's a quick spoiler... Why is the following true?

$$\det \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2\\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 2 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} =\det \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 2\\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 1\\ 2 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 2 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix} = \det \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 1\\ 2 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 2\\ 1 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 1  & 2 & 0 & 1\\ 2 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 0& 2 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 2 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix} = \dots $$

---

Consider the matrix
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2\\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 2 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\,.$$
It can be easily evaluated that $\det A = 4$.

More in general it's easy to show (by direct calculation) that given $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and defining
$$A(x) = \begin{pmatrix} x-1 & x & x+1 \\ x & x-1 & x \\ x+1 & x & x-1\end{pmatrix}$$
then $\det A(x) = 4x$.

The interesting fact is that these matrices can be "expanded" in a way such that the determinant is invariant. Additionally, for a larger class of matrices there seems to be some "simple" regular patterns concerning the determinant.

**Introducing some notation...**

First, I need to introduce some notation. Let $\mathbf{c} = \{c_1,c_2\dots c_n\}$. I'll denote $T(\mathbf{c})$ the $n\times n$ symmetric Toeplix matrix whose principal and upper diagonals are given by the coefficients $c_1\dots c_n$. I mean something like
$$T(\{c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4\}) = \begin{pmatrix} c_1 & c_2 & c_3 & c_4\\c_2 & c_1 & c_2 & c_3 \\ c_3 & c_2 & c_1 & c_2 \\ c_4 & c_3 & c_2 & c_1  \end{pmatrix}\,.$$

If we call $\mathbf{v}(x) = \{x-1,x,x+1\}$, then $A(x) = T(\mathbf{v}(x))$.

Finally, given a $n$-dimensional vector $\mathbf{c} = \{c_1\dots c_n\}$, I'll call $\mathbf{c}^k$ the $(k\cdot n)$-dimensional vector obtained joining together $k$ copies of $\mathbf{c}$. For example
$$\{c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4\}^3 = \{c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4,c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4,c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4\}\,.$$

**The main question**

I've stated at the beginning that $\det A(x) = 4x$. With the above notation, $\det T(\mathbf{v}(x)) = 4x$. Actually it seems to be true (at least for what I've tried with Mathematica) that for all positive integer $k$
$$\det T(\mathbf{v}^k(x)) = 4x\,.$$
I guess this result can be proven by induction on $k$, but it seems to be a bit painful. I would expect some simple and clean proof for what seems to be such a neat result.

Any ideas about what's going on and why the determinants are so simple?

**Going a bit further...**

Having noticed that things were so simple for $\mathbf{v}(x)=\{x-1,x,x+1\}$, the first thing I've tried is to slightly change $\mathbf{v}$. Let's now consider $T(\{x-2,x-1,x,x+1,x+2\}^k)$. Unfortunatly in this case things get much more complicated. For $k=1$ the determinant is $16 x$. But then for $k=2$ it's $113288 x$, for $k=3$ $65157184 x$ and so on. Things are clearly much messier here.

But... Let's define $\mathbf{w}(x) = \{x+2,x-1,x,x+1,x-2\}$. Then the sequence of determinants seems to be very regular.

\begin{align}
&\det T(\mathbf{w}(x)) = 16 x\\
&\det T(\mathbf{w}^2(x)) = -8 x\\
&\det T(\mathbf{w}^3(x)) = 0\\
&\det T(\mathbf{w}^4(x)) = -8 x\\
&\det T(\mathbf{w}^5(x)) = 16 x\\
&\det T(\mathbf{w}^6(x)) = -8 x\\
&\det T(\mathbf{w}^7(x)) = 0\\
&\det T(\mathbf{w}^8(x)) = -8 x
\end{align}
and so on. So there is a clear pattern in the dependence on $k$:
$$\{16, -8, 0, -8, 16, -8, 0, -8, 16, -8, 0, -8, 16, -8, 0, -8, 16, -8, 0, -8,\dots\}\,.$$

Then we may look at $T(\{x-3,x+2,x-1,x,x+1,x-2,x+3\})$ and again there is a pattern:
$$\{64, 12, 4, 0, 4, 12, 64, 12, 4, 0, 4, 12, 64, 12, 4, 0, 4, 12, 64, \dots\}\,.$$

And again for $T(\{x+4,x-3,x+2,x-1,x,x+1,x-2,x+3,x-4\})$ a new pattern:
$$\{256, -16, 0, -16, 0, -16, 0, -16, 256, -16, 0, -16, 0, -16, 0, -16, 256, -16, 0, -16,\dots\}\,.$$

I would bet in the existence of a simple explanation for these patterns, but as for now I've really no clue. Any ideas?

Comment: It might not actually be too painful to prove it inductively. Consider the formulae [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices) for the determinant of a block matrix.

Answer (score 6):

I will focus on $\mathbf v$, but the explanation holds for $\mathbf w$ as well. Note that we can write
$$
T(\mathbf v^k(x)) = xJ + T(\mathbf v^k(0)),
$$
where $J$ is the matrix of all $1$s. That is, $J = \mathbf e \mathbf e^T$, where $\mathbf e = (1,\dots,1)^T$. Note that in all cases you consider, $T_0$ has a row-sum of zero and therefore fails to be invertible. Now, with the [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma), we find that
$$
\det[T(\mathbf v^k(x))] = \det(T_0) + (\mathbf e^T\operatorname{adj}(T_0) \mathbf e) \cdot x = (\mathbf e^T\operatorname{adj}(T_0) \mathbf e) \cdot x.
$$
In other words, it will always be equal to some constant multiplied by $x$.

---

In fact, we can say a bit more: in the case where $\operatorname{adj}(T_0) \neq 0$, $T_0$ must be a symmetric matrix whose kernel is spanned by $\mathbf e$. It follows that we can write
$$
\operatorname{adj}(T_0) = \alpha \frac{\mathbf e\mathbf e^T}{\mathbf e^T\mathbf e} = \frac{\alpha}{kn} \mathbf e\mathbf e^T,
$$
where $\alpha$ is the product of the non-zero eigenvalues of $T_0$. For a direct computation, we see that $\alpha/(kn)$ is the bottom-right entry of the adjugate.  By the cofactor formula for the adjugate, this is the determinant of the symmetric, Toeplitz matrix attained by deleting the last row and column of $T_0$.

Once that is established, we note that
$$
(\mathbf e^T\operatorname{adj}(T_0) \mathbf e) = \frac{\alpha}{kn} (\mathbf e^T\mathbf e \mathbf e^T \mathbf e) = \alpha kn,
$$
So that our overall formula becomes $T(\mathbf v^k(x)) = (\alpha kn)\cdot x$.

---

For any vector $\mathbf v = (v_1,\dots,v_n)$, denote  the truncated vector $[\mathbf v] = (v_1,\dots,v_{n-1})$. With the above established, we have reduced your observations of regularity to the the computation of the determinants of $\det T([\mathbf v^k(0)])$ and $\det T([\mathbf w^k(0)])$.

Comment: Thanks @Ben ! But is actually easier the problem of proving the regularity of $\det T([\mathbf v^k(0)])$ and $\det T([\mathbf w^k(0)])$?

Comment: @ECL The advantage is that now we no longer need to compute the determinant of a matrix with the variable $x$ in it. So yes, I think that should make things easier.

Comment: $T_0\mathbf e\ne0$, isn't it?

Comment: (If I correctly understand the notation, the kernel of $T_0$ is rather generated by smth like $(1,0,\ldots,0,1)^T$)

Comment: @Startwearingpurple You're right! Not sure how I made that mistake.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Well it doesn't change the conclusions much. My take on was this: once we know that the determinant is linear in $x$, add the first raw of the matrix to the last one so that all of its elements become $2x$ which we can factor and set $x$ to $0$ in the rest. Then, similarly adding the first column to the last one, we get all elements of the last column, except the last one, equal to $0$. This gives the "truncated" determinant. Perhaps it's a bit simpler than your approach but in essence it's the same idea...